# debug1: Offering public key: username@hostname

Tags: ssh

i am trying to configure my laptop with my old keys. However there is still one ssh key missing. During a ssh -v connection, I have the following key still available on my old machine but not the new one:

```
...
debug1: Offering public key: username@hostname
...
```

How do I export this key ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to use the following top list all available keys:

```
ssh-add -L
```

given this output, it is easy to track the public/private key pair used.